# Remove unnecessary tag content from html source using scrapy

Tags: python, xml, scrapy

I am extracting html source of a web page using scrapy and save the output in .xml format. The web page source has the following content

```
<html> 
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">var startTime = new Date().getTime();
         </script><script type="text/javascript">var startTime = new
          Date().getTime();  </script> <script type="text/javascript">  
          document.cookie = "jsEnabled=true";..........  
        ...........<div style="margin: 0px">Required content</div>
</head>
</html>
```

From this I need to remove all

```
<script>....</script>
```

tags and retain the required content with their respective tags.
How can I do that by using scrapy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `lxml` package to remove element.

```
import lxml.etree as et
from lxml.etree import HTMLParser
from StringIO import StringIO 

def parse(self, response):
    parser = HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8', recover=True)
    tree = et.parse(StringIO(response.body), parser)
    for element in tree.xpath('//script'):
        element.getparent().remove(element)

    print et.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)
```

Comment: The line `import lxml.etree import HTMLParser` is incorrect. Do you mean `from lxml.etree import HTMLParser` or just `import HTMLParser`?

Answer (score 2):

The following code removes the 1 div in the text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag

markup = '<a>This is not div <div class="1">This is div 1</div><div class="2">This is div 2</div></a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup,"html.parser")

for tag in soup.select('div.1'):
  tag.decompose()

print(soup)
```

output:

```
<a>This is not div <div class="2">This is div 2</div></a>
```